# How to display the data / array from the filter function to view inside expression?

Tags: angularjs

This is what I have done

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">     
<table border="1" ng-init="ageToShow=(people| underTwenty: 20).length >= 1">
```

And my underTwenty Function is as under

```
myApp.filter('underTwenty', function() {

  return function(values, limit) {
    var returnValue = [];
    angular.forEach(values, function(val, ind) {
      if (val.age < limit)

        returnValue.push(val);
        });
  return returnValue;
  };
```

I want to display the **returnValue**  array in my View as expression like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">     
    <table border="1" ng-init="ageToShow=(people| underTwenty: 20).length >= 1">
{{ageToShow}}
```

I know this is not the proper way, but what it is..please help...

**Plunker** : http://plnkr.co/edit/ceeF5tXFlBqInW5J3bdq?p=preview

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to achieve, in plain English? Given the list of people, what should the page display?

Comment: "I want to display the returnValue array in my View as expression like this"

in that case you do not need to check length in ageToShow. Your question is not clear. See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LNhiN71UQu2bdCUIw8SR?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the updated code here:

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">


<table border="1" ng-init="ageToShow=(people| underTwenty: 20).length >= 1">

  {{people| underTwenty: 20}}
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th ng-if="!ageToShow">Age</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="person in people| underTwenty: 20"  >
<td><span>{{person.id}}</span>
</td>
<td><span>{{person.name}}</span>
</td>
<td ng-if="!ageToShow"><span>{{person.age}}</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this is the one you want

Comment: when i try to give {{people}} has an expression  in a html page im getting .............. [{"id":1,"name":"Peter","age":25},{"id":2,"name":"David","age":19},{"id":3,"name‌​":"Anil","age":30},{"id":4,"name":"Chean","age":20},{"id":5,"name":"Niladri","age‌​":18}]                but what i need is the filtered array....... only {"id":2,"name":"David","age":19}, .....{"id":5,"name":"Niladri","age‌​":18} to be displayed

Comment: You could use this  {{people| underTwenty: 20}}

Comment: Welcome @anilchean Accept it as an answer so that others also can get help

Answer (score 1):

In controller add new filter function:

```
$scope.criteriaMatch = function( criteria ) {
  return function( person ) {
    return person.age  < criteria;
  };
```

And in view change to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter:criteriaMatch(20)"  >
```

And table show ony 2 rows with age less 20

http://plnkr.co/edit/PonnLcvrjEEHhceSqD0g?p=preview

Comment: but im not asking about the table data wat i need is a raw data which will be lik dis {"id":2,"name":"David","age":19}, .....{"id":5,"name":"Niladri","age‌​":18} ......

Answer (score 1):

In your `ng-repeat`, pipe multiple filters to filter the people based on age as well.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter: search | underTwenty: 20"  >
```

I prefer your approach of keeping the filter separately instead of in the controller because, you can reuse that filter in other views as well if required. Else you may need to copy paste that code in multiple controllers.

But keeping the login in view is a bad idea. Instead In your controller, you can create that variable and check. This will remove the presentation from the logic.

It will become:

```
$scope.ageToShow = $filter('underTwenty')($scope.people, 20).length >= 1;
```

inject $`filter` into your controller.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rqAkDGyLlB0bVhOJ0NaE?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in your code: `<tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter: search"  >` to `<tr ng-repeat="person in people| underTwenty: 20"  >`. Due to this, the table will contain only those items where the age is less then 20. (As far as I understood this is what you wanted.)